# makes zend framework error reporting more user friendly

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to zendframework. Now i am facing problem with error reporting; when i makes small mistakes it's show me a long error message like this

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)' in /var/www/html/workbench/zend/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:248 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/workbench/lajeesh/zend/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #1 /var/www/html/workbench/lajeesh/zend/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(212): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #2 /var/www/html/workbench/sudeepc/zend/web_root/index.php(10): Zend_Controller_Front::run('../application/...') #3 {main} Next exception 'Zend_Controller_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)#0 /var/www/html/workbench/lajeesh/zend/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #1 /var/www/html/workbench/lajeesh/zend/library/Zend/Controller/Front.ph in /var/www/html/workbench/lajeesh/zend/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line 336
```

and so on.... . so my question is how can i configure zend framework error reporting more user friendly ?

Comment: You could try reading the error message - within it is a very clear description of what your problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error management is done in the following files..you can customize the way you want
1.ErrorController
2.error/error.phtml

ErrorController.php

```
<?php

class ErrorController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

        public function init()
        {
            $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('set your default layout here'); //so it will be much more nicer
        }

    public function errorAction()
    {
        $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

        if (!$errors) {
            $this->view->message = 'You have reached the error page';
            return;
        }

        switch ($errors->type) {
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:

                // 404 error -- controller or action not found
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
                $this->view->message = PackAssist_Locale::translate('Sorry, the page doesnt exists'); //This is a custom message
                break;
            default:
                // application error
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
                $this->view->message = 'Application error'; // put any custom messages if you want
                break;
        }

        // Log exception, if logger available
        if ($log = $this->getLog()) {
            $log->crit($this->view->message, $errors->exception);
        }

        // conditionally display exceptions
        if ($this->getInvokeArg('displayExceptions') == true) {
            $this->view->exception = $errors->exception;
        }

        $this->view->request   = $errors->request;
    }

    public function getLog()
    {
        $bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
        if (!$bootstrap->hasResource('Log')) {
            return false;
        }
        $log = $bootstrap->getResource('Log');
        return $log;
    }


}
```

error.phtml

```
<div>
  <h1><?php echo $this->translate('An error occurred');?></h1>
  <h2><?php echo $this->message; //Base error message ?></h2>

  <?php if (isset($this->exception)): ?>

  <h3><?php echo $this->translate('Exception information');?>:</h3>
  <p>
      <b>Message:</b> <?php echo $this->exception->getMessage(); ?>
  </p>

  <h3>Stack trace:</h3>
  <pre><?php  echo $this->exception->getTraceAsString(); //You can hide this for the end user ?>
  </pre>

  <h3>Request Parameters:</h3>
  <pre><?php  echo var_export($this->request->getParams(), true); // This will bea an array of your requested params POST/GET variables,your controller and the current action that produced the error ?>
  </pre>
```

3.If you want to completely hide the errors.just put these lines in your config file

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
```

Comment: ubercooluk thanks for your answer. But i am new to zendframework can explain how can i use this . i just tested the same by putting this: $this->view->assignz('resultSet','testing');   inside ErrorController.php but it's not working... Thanks.

Comment: If any error occour this controller will automatically executes..for example navigate to a non-existing action ..

Answer (score 1):

what i have done :
edit in library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php

find where there are :

```
 try {
        $controller->dispatch($action);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Clean output buffer on error
        $curObLevel = ob_get_level();
        if ($curObLevel > $obLevel) {
            do {
                ob_get_clean();
                $curObLevel = ob_get_level();
            } while ($curObLevel > $obLevel);
        }
        throw $e;
    }
```

it is just after :

```
/**
     * Dispatch the method call
     */
```

and add die($e->getMessage()); in the catch block : 
you will get :

```
  try {
        $controller->dispatch($action);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
        // Clean output buffer on error
        $curObLevel = ob_get_level();
        if ($curObLevel > $obLevel) {
            do {
                ob_get_clean();
                $curObLevel = ob_get_level();
            } while ($curObLevel > $obLevel);
        }
        throw $e;
    }
```

then the message delivered by Zend will be more explicit.